# Connecting Bebop drone with ROS

Tags: ros, bebop-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

i want to control my Bebop2 with ROS messages. I downloaded bebop_autonomy and catkin it. When I want to run the launch file, the driver is getting killed

There is no log file and I actually dont know, why I cant compile it.

I have:

- ROS Indigo
- Ubuntu 14.04
- Drone Firmware 3.9

Someone else had this problem? Is there another solution to use the drone with ROS?

PARAMETERS

```
/bebop/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
/rosdistro: indigo
/rosversion: 1.11.20
```

NODES

/bebop/

bebop_driver (bebop_driver/bebop_driver_node)

robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)

auto-starting new master

process[master]: started with pid [16121]

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 829426e2-7cda-11e6-8573-0024e8cfd983

process[rosout-1]: started with pid [16134]

started core service [/rosout]

process[bebop/bebop_driver-2]: started with pid [16141]

process[bebop/robot_state_publisher-3]: started with pid [16152]

INFO  [1474118862.405218917]: Initializing nodelet with 2 worker threads.

INFO  [1474118862.468457685]: [BebopSDK] 15:27:42:468 | Bebop:230 - Bebop Cnstr()

INFO  [1474118862.468590244]: Nodelet Cstr

INFO [1474118862.472868092]: Connecting to Bebop ...

INFO [1474118862.713580127]: [BebopSDK] 15:27:42:713 | CommandReceivedCallback:113 - Command

Received Callback LWP id is: 16268

ERROR [1474118862.867989008]: [ARCONTROLLER_Network] 15:27:42:867 |
ARCONTROLLER_Network_ReaderRun:940 - ARCOMMANDS_Decoder_DecodeBuffer () failed : 2
ARDrone3.PictureSettingsState.UNKNOWN -> Unknown co

ERROR [1474118862.871437212]: [ARCONTROLLER_Network] 15:27:42:871 | ARCONTROLLER_Network_ReaderRun:940 - ARCOMMANDS_Decoder_DecodeBuffer () failed : 2 ARDrone3.PictureSettingsState.UNKNOWN -> Unknown co

ERROR [1474118862.874543473]: [ARCONTROLLER_Network] 15:27:42:874 | ARCONTROLLER_Network_ReaderRun:940 - ARCOMMANDS_Decoder_DecodeBuffer () failed : 2 ARDrone3.PictureSettingsState.UNKNOWN -> Unknown co

ERROR [1474118862.940212578]: [ARCONTROLLER_Network] 15:27:42:940 | ARCONTROLLER_Network_ReaderRun:940 - ARCOMMANDS_Decoder_DecodeBuffer () failed : 2 common.CommonState.UNKNOWN -> Unknown command

INFO [1474118862.953768631]: [BebopSDK] 15:27:42:953 | Connect:326 - BebopSDK inited, lwp_id: 16141

INFO [1474118862.953857749]: Fetching all settings from the Drone ..
.
INFO [1474118863.071386661]: Value for GPSSettingsHomeTypeType recved: 0

INFO [1474118863.071473543]: [CB] 15:27:43:071 | Update:1703 - Checking if GPSSettingsHomeTypeType exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.073020388]: [CB] 15:27:43:072 | Update:1706 - No

ERROR [1474118863.092875287]: [ARCONTROLLER_Network] 15:27:43:092 | ARCONTROLLER_Network_ReaderRun:940 - ARCOMMANDS_Decoder_DecodeBuffer () failed : 2 ARDrone3.PictureSettingsState.UNKNOWN -> Unknown co

ERROR [1474118863.100761206]: [ARCONTROLLER_Network] 15:27:43:100 | ARCONTROLLER_Network_ReaderRun:940 - ARCOMMANDS_Decoder_DecodeBuffer () failed : 2 ARDrone3.PictureSettingsState.UNKNOWN -> Unknown co

ERROR [1474118863.104702699]: [ARCONTROLLER_Network] 15:27:43:104 | ARCONTROLLER_Network_ReaderRun:940 - ARCOMMANDS_Decoder_DecodeBuffer () failed : 2 ARDrone3.PictureSettingsState.UNKNOWN -> Unknown co

INFO [1474118863.189877636]: Value for PilotingSettingsMaxAltitudeCurrent recved: 30

INFO [1474118863.189995598]: [CB] 15:27:43:189 | Update:111 - Checking if
PilotingSettingsMaxAltitudeCurrent exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.191580856]: [CB] 15:27:43:191 | Update:114 - No

INFO [1474118863.193173377]: Value for PilotingSettingsMaxDistanceValue recved: 160

INFO [1474118863.193235326]: [CB] 15:27:43:193 | Update:352 - Checking if PilotingSettingsMaxDistanceValue exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.194297682]: [CB] 15:27:43:194 | Update:355 - No

INFO [1474118863.200952648]: Value for PilotingSettingsNoFlyOverMaxDistanceShouldnotflyover recved: 0

INFO [1474118863.201026121]: [CB] 15:27:43:201 | Update:432 - Checking if PilotingSettingsNoFlyOverMaxDistanceShouldnotflyover exists in params ...

INFO] [1474118863.202526521]: [CB] 15:27:43:202 | Update:435 - No

INFO [1474118863.204033976]: Value for PilotingSettingsMaxTiltCurrent recved: 20

INFO [1474118863.204078953]: [CB] 15:27:43:204 | Update:191 - Checking if PilotingSettingsMaxTiltCurrent exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.204989544]: [CB] 15:27:43:204 | Update:194 - No

INFO [1474118863.206983024]: Value for PilotingSettingsAbsolutControlOn recved: 0

INFO [1474118863.207043856]: [CB] 15:27:43:207 | Update:271 - Checking if PilotingSettingsAbsolutControlOn exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.207771113]: [CB] 15:27:43:207 | Update:274 - No

INFO [1474118863.219866157]: Value for PilotingSettingsBankedTurnValue recved: 0

INFO [1474118863.219941096]: [CB] 15:27:43:219 | Update:513 - Checking if PilotingSettingsBankedTurnValue exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.221278557]: [CB] 15:27:43:221 | Update:516 - No

INFO [1474118863.222701014]: Value for SpeedSettingsMaxVerticalSpeedCurrent recved: 1

INFO [1474118863.222754303]: [CB] 15:27:43:222 | Update:1075 - Checking if SpeedSettingsMaxVerticalSpeedCurrent exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.223785230]: [CB] 15:27:43:223 | Update:1078 - No

INFO [1474118863.225613466]: Value for SpeedSettingsMaxRotationSpeedCurrent recved: 100

INFO [1474118863.225654602]: [CB] 15:27:43:225 | Update:1155 - Checking if SpeedSettingsMaxRotationSpeedCurrent exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.226362234]: [CB] 15:27:43:226 | Update:1158 - No

INFO [1474118863.234484077]: Value for SpeedSettingsHullProtectionPresent recved: 0

INFO [1474118863.234542464]: [CB] 15:27:43:234 | Update:1235 - Checking if
SpeedSettingsHullProtectionPresent exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.235710071]: [CB] 15:27:43:235 | Update:1238 - No

INFO [1474118863.237468674]: Value for SpeedSettingsOutdoorOutdoor recved: 1

INFO [1474118863.237520497]: [CB] 15:27:43:237 | Update:1315 - Checking if SpeedSettingsOutdoorOutdoor exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.238472852]: [CB] 15:27:43:238 | Update:1318 - No

INFO [1474118863.251575217]: Value for SpeedSettingsMaxPitchRollRotationSpeedCurrent recved: 300

INFO [1474118863.251644220]: [CB] 15:27:43:251 | Update:1395 - Checking if SpeedSettingsMaxPitchRollRotationSpeedCurrent exists in params ...

INFO 1474118863.252927833]: [CB] 15:27:43:252 | Update:1398 - No

INFO [1474118863.254569382]: Value for NetworkSettingsWifiSelectionType recved: 1

INFO [1474118863.254622043]: [CB] 15:27:43:254 | Update:1501 - Checking if
NetworkSettingsWifiSelectionType exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.255588437]: [CB] 15:27:43:255 | Update:1504 - No

INFO [1474118863.258823625]: Value for NetworkSettingsWifiSelectionBand recved: 0

INFO [1474118863.259016945]: [CB] 15:27:43:258 | Update:1522 - Checking if NetworkSettingsWifiSelectionBand exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.259923764]: [CB] 15:27:43:259 | Update:1525 - No

INFO [1474118863.260750476]: Value for NetworkSettingsWifiSelectionChannel recved: 6

INFO [1474118863.260784000]: [CB] 15:27:43:260 | Update:1543 - Checking if NetworkSettingsWifiSelectionChannel exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.261342241]: [CB] 15:27:43:261 | Update:1546 - No

INFO [1474118863.290460818]: Value for PictureSettingsVideoStabilizationModeMode recved: 0

INFO [1474118863.290513059]: [CB] 15:27:43:290 | Update:1623 - Checking if PictureSettingsVideoStabilizationModeMode exists in params ...

INFO [1474118863.291447187]: [CB] 15:27:43:291 | Update:1626 - No

ERROR [1474118863.293378298]: [ARCONTROLLER_Network] 15:27:43:293 | ARCONTROLLER_Network_ReaderRun:940 - ARCOMMANDS_Decoder_DecodeBuffer () failed : 2
ARDrone3.PictureSettingsState.UNKNOWN -> Unknown co

[ERROR] [1474118863.296448102]: [ARCONTROLLER_Network] 15:27:43:296 | ARCONTROLLER_Network_ReaderRun:940 - ARCOMMANDS_Decoder_DecodeBuffer () failed : 2
ARDrone3.PictureSettingsState.UNKNOWN -> Unknown co

[ERROR] [1474118863.315566944]: [ARCONTROLLER_Network] 15:27:43:315 | ARCONTROLLER_Network_ReaderRun:940 - ARCOMMANDS_Decoder_DecodeBuffer () failed : 2 ARDrone3.PictureSettingsState.UNKNOWN -> Unknown co

INFO] [1474118863.330631988]: Value for GPSSettingsReturnHomeDelayDelay recved: 60

[ INFO] [1474118863.330693518]: [CB] 15:27:43:330 | Update:1783 - Checking if
GPSSettingsReturnHomeDelayDelay exists in params ...

INFO] [1474118863.333176795]: [CB] 15:27:43:333 | Update:1786 - No

INFO] [1474118863.336192262]: Value for GPSSettingsHomeTypeType recved: 0

INFO] [1474118863.336302541]: [CB] 15:27:43:336 | Update:1703 - Checking if GPSSettingsHomeTypeType exists in params ...

INFO] [1474118863.338623088]: [CB] 15:27:43:338 | Update:1711 - Yes

INFO] [1474118866.113073247]: Dynamic reconfigure callback with level: -1

INFO] [1474118866.136688121]: Enabling video stream ...

WARN] [1474118866.136829969]: [BebopSDK] 15:27:46:136 | StartStreaming:364 - Video streaming started ...

INFO] [1474118866.136956032]: Nodelet lwp_id: 16141

INFO] [1474118866.137009601]: bebop_driver nodelet loaded.

INFO] [1474118866.137100045]: [CameraThread] thread lwp_id: 16463

INFO] [1474118866.137190559]: [AuxThread] thread lwp_id: 16464

WARN] [1474118866.158027497]: [ARSTREAM2_H264Filter] 15:27:46:157 | ARSTREAM2_H264Filter_RtpReceiverNaluCallback:1201 - ARSTREAM2_RtpReceiver NALU buffer is too small, truncated AU (or maybe it's the fi

WARN] [1474118866.167337480]: [ARSTREAM2_H264Filter] 15:27:46:167 | ARSTREAM2_H264Filter_enqueueCurrentAu:481 - AU output cancelled (waitForSync)

WARN] [1474118866.201722369]: [ARSTREAM2_H264Filter] 15:27:46:201 | ARSTREAM2_H264Filter_enqueueCurrentAu:481 - AU output cancelled (waitForSync)

WARN] [1474118866.231175626]: [ARSTREAM2_H264Filter] 15:27:46:231 | ARSTREAM2_H264Filter_enqueueCurrentAu:481 - AU output cancelled (waitForSync)

WARN] [1474118866.266660026]: [ARSTREAM2_H264Filter] 15:27:46:266 | ARSTREAM2_H264Filter_enqueueCurrentAu:481 - AU output cancelled (waitForSync)

WARN] [1474118866.292939904]: [ARSTREAM2_H264Filter] 15:27:46:292 | ARSTREAM2_H264Filter_sync:161 - SPS/PPS sync OK

INFO] [1474118866.292996196]: [BebopSDK] 15:27:46:292 | DecoderConfigCallback:147 - H264 configuration packet received: #SPS: 27 #PPS: 9 (MP4? 0)

WARN] [1474118866.293077003]: [ARSTREAM2_H264Filter] 15:27:46:293 | ARSTREAM2_H264Filter_generateGrayIFrame:568 - Waiting for a slice to generate gray I-frame

WARN] [1474118866.293136577]: [ARSTREAM2_H264Filter] 15:27:46:293 | ARSTREAM2_H264Filter_generateGrayIFrame:568 - Waiting for a slice to generate gray I-frame

WARN] [1474118866.293288622]: [ARSTREAM2_H264Filter] 15:27:46:293 | ARSTREAM2_H264Filter_generateGrayIFrame:618 - Gray I slice NALU output size: 1629

INFO] [1474118866.293336323]: [BebopSDK] 15:27:46:293 | FrameReceivedCallback:174 - Frame Recv & Decode LWP id: 16466

INFO] [1474118866.295966127]: [Decoder] 15:27:46:295 | InitCodec:133 - H264 Codec is initialized!

INFO [1474118866.296011175]: [Decoder] 15:27:46:295 | Decode:235 - Updating H264 codec parameters (Buffer Size: 36) ...

[bebop/bebop_driver-2] process has died [pid 16141, exit code -11, cmd /home/dennis/bebop_ws/devel/lib/bebop_driver/bebop_driver_node __name:=bebop_driver __log:=/home/dennis/.ros/log/829426e2-7cda-11e6-8573-0024e8cfd983/bebop-bebop_driver-2.log].
log file: /home/dennis/.ros/log/829426e2-7cda-11e6-8573-0024e8cfd983/bebop-bebop_driver-2*.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243933/connecting-bebop-drone-with-ros/) by [Trinto](https://answers.ros.org/users/27573/trinto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-09-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Trinto](https://answers.ros.org/users/27573/trinto/) on 2016-09-19**:
Its about the ARSTREAM2_H264 . Its sending do driver and he is killing the driver..

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2016-09-19**:
Have you tried using this [catkinized version of ARSDK](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/parrot_arsdk)? Try building that from source and then checkout and build the dev branch `2-parrot-sdk` in *bebop_autonomy*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem by myself.
Upgrading the SDK ( in bebop_autonomy under the hood are the steps for it ). Its difficult, because there is no new revision key. You have change the hash in generate.py to master/xml + chance the xml-tags at the end ( ardrone3.xml and Command.xml ) and in url-mustache its not libARCommands , its arsdk-xml and chance Xml to xml. Then delete ALL .xml in all filenames and in the files !
After chance in ardrone3_setting_callbacks.h pilotingsettingsstate_maxdistance_value to .._current, the both circling_xx_values with current to and something like bankedterm value to STATE.
After you can catkin the workspace.

the next prob is, that the driver is dying, cause the new frames are to big. So give the frames more space in bebop_decode.cpp

Now you can communicate with the drone.

---

Originally posted by [Trinto](https://answers.ros.org/users/27573/trinto/) with karma: 16 on 2016-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0